# Parameter "@xxx" has already been defined

Tags: c#, mysql

I have the code below and when it enters into the ForEach loop, the error hapens.

I read this

[StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925258/sql-error-c-sharp-parameter-already-defined)

But didnt made it =\ I need to know what do I have to change. I tryed to move the MySqlCommand, but didnt solve the problem... Thanks
I had 3 different methods (Select,Insert,Update) But i had to use "Transaction" So I puted the 3 methods at the same... First time it works fine, but the second loop throught the error happens in the **INSERT QUERY**

```
#region Querys
        string Select = @"SELECT id_convidado, nome, cod_dependente, dt_insercao, matricula FROM convidado_acesso WHERE debpag = 0 AND status <> 'Devolvido'";

        string Insert = @"INSERT INTO debpag (
                     numero_int,
                     parcela,
                     tipo_pessoa,
                     matricula,
                     cod_dependente,
                     ev_financeiro,
                     quantidade,
                     valor_unitario,
                     valor_total,
                     dt_lancamento,
                     dt_vencimento,
                     dt_pagamento,
                     dt_insercao,
                     dt_insercao_pagamento,
                     referencia,
                     cobrador_lancto,
                     cobrador_pagto,
                     usr_lancto,
                     forma_pagto)
                     VALUES (
                     @numero_int,
                     @parcela,
                     @tipo_pessoa,
                     @matricula,
                     @cod_dependente,
                     @ev_financeiro,
                     @quantidade,
                     @valor_unitario,
                     @valor_total,
                     @dt_lancamento,
                     @dt_vencimento,
                     @dt_pagamento,
                     @dt_insercao,
                     @dt_insercao_pagamento,
                     @referencia,
                     @cobrador_lancto,
                     @cobrador_pagto,
                     @usr_lancto,
                     @forma_pagto)";

        string Update = "UPDATE convidado_acesso SET dt_saida = @dt_saida, usr_saida= @usr_saida, status= @status, debpag = @deb WHERE nome = @nome AND debpag = 0";
        #endregion

        #region MySql
        MySqlConnection conexao = conexao = new MySqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database = crdores; Uid= root;Pwd = ik9rru2j;Allow Zero Datetime = true");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conexao;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = Select;
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        conexao.Open();
        ta = conexao.BeginTransaction();

        #endregion


        try
        {
            #region TratamentoSelect


            List<Convidado> convidado = null;
            Convidado retorno = null;
            if ((ds.Tables.Count > 0) && (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0))
            {
                convidado = new List<Convidado>();
                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {



                    string status = "";
                    int deb = 0;

                    retorno = new Convidado();
                    try
                    {
                        retorno.Nome = row["nome"].ToString();
                    }
                    catch { }
                    try
                    {
                        retorno.Cod_Dep = Convert.ToInt32(row["cod_dependente"]);
                    }
                    catch { }
                    try
                    {
                        retorno.Dt_Insercao = Convert.ToDateTime(row["dt_insercao"]);
                    }
                    catch { }
                    try
                    {
                        retorno.Matricula = Convert.ToInt32(row["matricula"]);
                    }
                    catch { }
                    try
                    {
                        retorno.Id_Convidado = Convert.ToInt32(row["id_convidado"]);
                    }
                    catch { }

                    #region Variaveis


                    string tmp = BuscaTempoLimite();
                    int z = tmp.Length;
                    string h = tmp.Remove(1, z - 1);
                    string m = tmp.Remove(0, 2);

                    string saida = BuscaHoraServidor();
                    retorno.Dt_Insercao = retorno.Dt_Insercao.AddMinutes(15);
                    string entrada = retorno.Dt_Insercao.ToString("HH:mm");
                    DateTime insercao = Convert.ToDateTime(retorno.Dt_Insercao);
                    DateTime left = Convert.ToDateTime(saida);
                    saida = left.ToString("HH:mm");

                    int horaEntrada = Convert.ToInt32(entrada.Remove(2, 3));
                    int minutosEntrada = Convert.ToInt32(entrada.Remove(0, 3));
                    int horaSaida = Convert.ToInt32(saida.Remove(2, 3));
                    int minutosSaida = Convert.ToInt32(saida.Remove(0, 3));
                    TimeSpan first = new TimeSpan(horaEntrada, minutosEntrada, 0);
                    TimeSpan last = new TimeSpan(horaSaida, minutosSaida, 0);
                    TimeSpan result = last - first;
                    TimeSpan limite = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(h), Convert.ToInt32(m), 59);

                    int hora = last.Hours - first.Hours;
                    int minutosss = last.Minutes - first.Minutes;

                    result = new TimeSpan(hora, minutosss, 0);
                    #endregion

                    if (left.Day <= insercao.Day)
                    {
                        if (result > limite)
                        {
                            status = "Pago";
                            deb = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            status = "Devolvido";
                            deb = 2;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        status = "Pago";
                    }



            #endregion

                    #region TratamentoInsert

                    cmd.CommandText = Insert;

                    #region váriaveis
                    int cash = 0;
                    string eventoF = "", usre = "", cobrador = "", tmpLimite = "";
                    int ide = 0;
                    ide = PegaMaxID();
                    string insercao_pagto;
                    string dt_lancamento = BuscaHoraServidor();
                    string saidaa = VerificaSaida(Convert.ToInt32(retorno.Id_Convidado));
                    string referencia = retorno.Dt_Insercao.ToString("MM/yyyy");
                    if (saida != "")
                    {
                        insercao_pagto = saida;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        insercao_pagto = BuscaHoraServidor();
                    }

                    int tipo_pessoa;
                    if (retorno.Cod_Dep > 0)
                    {
                        tipo_pessoa = 3;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tipo_pessoa = 1;
                    }

                    retorno.Dt_Insercao = retorno.Dt_Insercao.AddHours(1);
                    retorno.Dt_Insercao = retorno.Dt_Insercao.AddMinutes(15);
                    retorno.Dt_Insercao = retorno.Dt_Insercao.AddSeconds(59);
                    string ent = retorno.Dt_Insercao.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    #endregion

                    DataSet confg = pag.BuscaConfigs();
                    foreach (DataRow roww in confg.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        eventoF = roww["ev_financeiro"].ToString();
                        cash = Convert.ToInt32(roww["valor"]);
                        usre = roww["usr_insercao"].ToString();
                        tmpLimite = roww["tempo_permanencia"].ToString();
                        cobrador = roww["cod_cobrador"].ToString();
                    }

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@numero_int", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = ide + 1; **//HERE THE ERROR STARTS**
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@parcela", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = "1/1";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@tipo_pessoa", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = tipo_pessoa;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@matricula", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = retorno.Matricula;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@cod_dependente", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = retorno.Cod_Dep;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@ev_financeiro", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = eventoF;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@quantidade", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = 1;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@valor_unitario", MySqlDbType.Double)).Value = Convert.ToDouble(cash);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@valor_total", MySqlDbType.Double)).Value = Convert.ToDouble(cash);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dt_lancamento", MySqlDbType.Date)).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dt_lancamento); //  X
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dt_vencimento", MySqlDbType.Date)).Value = ent; // X
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dt_pagamento", MySqlDbType.Date)).Value = saida; //  X
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dt_insercao", MySqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = saida; //  X
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dt_insercao_pagamento", MySqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = insercao_pagto; // X
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@referencia", MySqlDbType.Date)).Value = referencia;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@cobrador_lancto", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = cobrador;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@cobrador_pagto", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = cobrador;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@usr_lancto", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = usre;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@forma_pagto", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = 1;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    #endregion

                    #region TratamentoUpdate

                    cmd.CommandText = Update;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dt_saida", MySqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = conv.Dt_Saida;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@usr_saida", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = usuario;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@status", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = status;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@deb", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = deb;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@nome", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = retorno.Nome;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    #endregion

                    ta.Commit();

                }
            }
        }
```

`Cmd.Parameter.Clear()` Is not a good practise. Here's the ANSWER.

Outside the ForEachLoop :

```
Cmd.Parameter.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Hellow", MySqlDataType));
```

Inside the ForEachLoop

```
Cmd.Parameter["@Hellow"].Value = anyValueOrVariable;
```

Comment: I asked, showed my problem, and someone answered me, i gave enough information for them to answer me, it is not enough for you, there's nothing wrong with the question, but with who couldn't answer =)

Thanks for your 'tip'.

Comment: You should mark one of the answers as the correct answer - it helps people to know which question helped and also feeds peoples reputation addiction so they keep coming back to answer your questions. If you don't upvote useful answers and accept answers a lot of people will stop answering any question you have.

Comment: Sorry my dumbish, but how I dod that? I just see the "Rate Answer"

Comment: The question is fine and far from incomplete or vague. I've had exactly the same problem here but it's a simple solution as one of the answer is showing. Why closing such a question instead of just marking the answer from Russel as the answer.

Answer (score 12):

You're adding the same parameters to your command over and over again in the loop. The exception is telling you the problem.

Either store your parameters outside the loop and reset the values or clear the parameters each time through the loop.

The quickest solution would be something like this:

```
  #region TratamentoInsert
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();//<--clear all the parameters.
                    cmd.CommandText = Insert;
```

Not sure if that's the exact code to clear the parameters collection or not but I'm late for a flight and can't check. It'll be something like that.

Comment: Thanks Russel Troywest, wish everyone were like you and Wilson, and again, sorry if I did somethign wrong with the question... I Just dont get it, really ! Thanks Russel (=

I Did what you and Simon said and worked perfect !

Comment: Ignore the downvotes. People just get grumpy on a Friday ;)

Comment: Cmd.parameter.clear() is right, but NOT GOOD practise ;s
You have to :

Cmd.Parameter.Add(New MySqlParameter("@hello", MySqlDataType.Varchar)) <-OUtSide the foreach

And inside the foreach you just

cmd.parameter["@hello"].Value = variable;

DONE =)

Comment: Yes,alan is completely correct on this and that is what you should do.like i said, running late for a flight and the solution i gave was the simplest to implement. Storing the parameters outside the loop is a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding parameters to `cmd` on every loop. Create the parameters at the same point you initialize `cmd`, or clear them before adding again.

Comment: Thanks Simon Wilson ! It worked just fine. And I'm sorry if i did somethings wrong with the questions... Hope everyone was just like you are... Instead of comment here to say "its wrong negative rate blabla" you helped me =) Thanks !

If its to say i'm wrong with question make, do not spend your time with that ~* Only for helping !