# trouble inserting data typed in the data grid view into the databse system

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
        private void btnPostSale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string insert;

        insert = "INSERT INTO tblInvoiceLines(stockItems) VALUES (@stockItems)";//, itemDescription, quantity, sellingPrice, totalAmountInvoiceLines) VALUES (@stockItems, @itemDescription, @quantity, @sellingPrice, @totalAmountInvoiceLines)";

        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, con);

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //all the lines entered in datagrid view should be store in sql sever databse
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@stockItems", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value);
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("New data has being entered");
    }
```

> Im having trouble trying to insert my data into sql server whilre using a loop statement as I always get an expccetion error. please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFAW1.jpg)

Comment: this comes up a lot - but you arent ever running those commands. make a new command in youur loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL error C# - Parameter already defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925258/sql-error-c-sharp-parameter-already-defined)

Comment: @stockItems value has been set twice :
cmd.Parameters["@stockItems"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["stockItems"].Value;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stockItems", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["stockItems"].Value);

Comment: Can you try comment out first line in the for loop

Comment: i've edited a few things that i really need help with

Comment: @NgomanaFT you are missing the part where people say that the same parameter is being added multiple times. With your edit you are still doing the same thing. You try and add a parameter called `@stockItems` each time through your loop. Each parameter name must be unique for the instance of that `Parameters` collection.

Comment: @bc winiger Could you please assist me by writing what you saying in code form. I'm desperate right now.

Comment: You need to clear your parameters and execute your query inside the loop. Have you tried looking for some examples online? This is a common issue that has been covered thousands and thousands of times.